# The following error occur when I click on

Tags: android

Error:

```
 10-30 03:42:14.451: E/SQLiteLog(1633): (1) near "TEXT": syntax error
 10-30 03:42:14.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1633): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Create Table user_info(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,  name TEXT ,  bdate TEXT ,  adate TEXT ,  check TEXT ,  bmessage TEXT ,  amessage TEXT):
```

when this type of errors happen.

Here is given the sql code:

```
     String TABLE_SQL="Create Table "+TABLE_NAME
            +"(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "
            +" name TEXT , "
            +" bdate TEXT , "
            +" adate TEXT , "
            +" check TEXT , "
            +" bmessage TEXT , "
            +" amessage TEXT): ";
```

Comment: Replace : with ; in the end of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here arises two problems first one is syntax error and other is the variable name "check". We know check is a keyword to use in SQL. SO to recover from it we may change the variable name such as: checkSelection.

So the above code should be :`String TABLE_SQL="Create Table "+TABLE_NAME
            +"(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "
            +" name TEXT , "
            +" bdate TEXT , "
            +" adate TEXT , "
            +"checkSelection TEXT , " //here replaced 'check' with 'checkSelection' 
            +" bmessage TEXT , "
            +" amessage TEXT); ";// here replaced`:`with`;`

i think it is one of the right  way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
  String TABLE_SQL="Create Table "+TABLE_NAME
            +"(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "
            +" name TEXT , "
            +" bdate TEXT , "
            +" adate TEXT , "
            +" check TEXT , "
            +" bmessage TEXT , "
            +" amessage TEXT); ";// here,replace `:` with `;`
```

You had put `:` instead of `;` at the last line. So replace it with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:` at end of the line

```
String TABLE_SQL="Create Table "+TABLE_NAME
            +"(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "
            +" name TEXT , "
            +" bdate TEXT , "
            +" adate TEXT , "
            +" check TEXT , "
            +" bmessage TEXT , "
            +" amessage TEXT): ";
```

Replace above code with below,

```
String TABLE_SQL="Create Table "+TABLE_NAME
            +"(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "
            +" name TEXT , "
            +" bdate TEXT , "
            +" adate TEXT , "
            +" check TEXT , "
            +" bmessage TEXT , "
            +" amessage TEXT)";
```